sudo: inaccessible or not found after chmod 755
I have android 12 and muiu 14. I rooted the device with magisk and I have the latest version of magisk installed. I connected to my phone with adb shell and ran these commands. Because I was getting permission denied at sudo su
I did what this  thread did.
chmod 755 /
chmod 755 /bin
chmod 755 /lib

Then this error started happening:
/system/bin/sh: sudo: inaccessible or not found

How can I fix this ?
full log after chmod 755
surya:/ $ sudo
/system/bin/sh: sudo: inaccessible or not found
127|surya:/ $ su -
Permission denied


You've not provide any Ubuntu product or release details; however many system tools will refuse to work if they detect incorrect values; and that includes permissions... There are certain apps & config/data files you should NOT change if you need to use tools (eg. sudo, su).  Boot a live system and change those permissions back to expected (or what they were).

how can I fix this chmod, it started not detecting sudo after I ran.. also, for the phone I will see how to boot to live.

You've still not provided any Ubuntu product/release details; I suggested boot a live system as your existing permissions will be ignored and the live systems used instead; allowing you not suffer consequences of your prior action(s)...  Providing your Ubuntu product/release details of your system with problem (not Phone OS you mention, but Ubuntu system you want help with) allows us to be more clear; as this is a Ubuntu site providing help with Ubuntu OS problems.

Having a quick look at what permissions were (ie. from a backup you have etc) and you'll usually quickly notice some files/programs/configs have different permissions to what most do; those different permissions are usually a clue that those apps/tools require specific permissions, and that its risky to change them (ie. if changed they may not function, or function differently etc.. ie. you have a tool to explore why it has different permissions BEFORE you change them)

Also posted on Android.SE: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/259244/44325

OP was executing commands under Android's shell, and Android is not Ubuntu, so I think it's off-topic here. (Hint: su is not accessible on non-rooted Android devices)

already rooted the device
